# QT connect Signal from QDialog with Main Window

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qt-signals, slot

I'm probably missing something so basic, that I'll be ashamed once you point it out to me, but right now I've been working on this matter for nearly 3 days, so I think it might be time to get some help.

I have a QWizardProject on qt5 and for one of these pages I want a QPushButton, that launches a new Dialog, where I have a QCheckbox (among others). Signals from the QCheckbox should change the QLineEdit on the QWizardPage.
Sounds simple enough, I just can't get it to work - at all. I've tried out so many different versions of that (most of them failed building). The most recent version just does nothing. Thanks for any help in advance!

main.h

```
#ifndef main_H
#define main_H

#include <QWizard>
#include <QtWidgets>

class QCheckBox;
class QLabel;
class QLineEdit;
class QRadioButton;

class OMVGguiWizard : public QWizard
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum { Page_Main1, Page_Main2, Page_Main3};

    OMVGguiWizard(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

class Page_Main3 : public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT;

public:
    Mainpage_3(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void btnOptionsbuttonsClicked(QString mode);
private:
    QPushButton *OptionsButton;
    QLineEdit *receiver;
};

class FindDialog : public QDialog
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     FindDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
     QCheckBox *checkbox;
     QGridLayout *mainLayout;
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
Page_Main3::Page_Main3(QWidget *parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
{
    // ...

    DensifyOptionsButton = new QPushButton(tr("Densify Settings"));
    receiver = new QLineEdit(tr("empty"));

    connect(OptionsButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() { btnOptionsbuttonsClicked("field1"); });

    // ...
}

void Page_Main3::btnOptionsbuttonsClicked(QString mode)
{
     FindDialog *dialog = new FindDialog;
     dialog->show();
}

void Page_Main3::checkboxClicked()
{
receiver->setText("test");
}

FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent)
      : QDialog(parent)
{
     checkbox = new QCheckBox(tr("Advanced Options"));
     mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
     mainLayout->addWidget(checkbox);
     setLayout(mainLayout);
     connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Page_Main3::checkboxClicked() ) );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: What doesn't work? The push button doesn't launch the dialog? The checkbox doesn't change the text? Something else?

Comment: emitting / receiving the signal back to the mainwindow didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
 connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Page_Main3::checkboxClicked() ) );
```

The third argument - receiver - must be object whose slot called. In your case this must be Page_Main3, but you pass "this" - FindDialog.

You must pass signal from QcheckBox through FindDialog and connect to signal from FindDialog. Example:

```
class Page_Main3 : public QWizardPage
{
  ...
private slots:
    ...
    void OnCheckBoxClicked();
    ...
};

class FindDialog : public QDialog
{
   ...
signals:
    void checkboxClicked();
   ...
};

FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent)
{
     checkbox = new QCheckBox(tr("Advanced Options"));
     connect(checkbox, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &FindDialog::checkboxClicked);
     ...
}

void Page_Main3::btnOptionsbuttonsClicked(QString mode)
{
    FindDialog *dialog = new FindDialog(this);
    connect(dialog, &FindDialog::checkboxClicked, this, &Page_Main3::OnCheckBoxClicked);
    ...
}

void Page_Main3::OnCheckBoxClicked()
{
    receiver->setText("Checkbox clicked!");
}
```

Comment: you are very certainly right and the code you provided was well written and worked just fine. Thank you so much - I wish I could buy you a beer for that.